# Is there a way to copy S3 bucket properties from one bucket to another using the AWS CLI?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The title pretty much sums up my question. I am having no problem copying files from Bucket A to Bucket B, but I would also like to copy Bucket A properties to Bucket B from the cli (ie. setting static web hosting to enabled, or versioning to enabled etc.). Here is the commands I am running right now:

```
aws s3 mb s3://$S3_NEW_BUCKET_NAME
aws s3 sync s3://$S3_PROD_BUCKET_NAME/ s3://$S3_NEW_BUCKET_NAME/
```

Comment: AWS CLI doesn't have a mechanism for this

Comment: I don't know that you can copy all of the properties over, but I don't see why you couldn't query the ones that you're interested in, and then set those in an AWS CLI call...